# what happens if we input a character in a switch case where an integer is required

Tags: c++, integer, switch-statement, character

```
  do{
    cout<<"Enter the task to perform \n";
    cout<<"1. push an element \n";
    cout<<"2. pop an element \n";
    cout<<"3. peep the elements \n";
    cout<<"4. retain odd elements \n";
    cout<<"5. remove till element n \n";
    cout<<"6. Display the elements \n";
    cout<<"7. exit \n";
    cin>>a;
    switch(a){

        case 1:
        .
        .
        .
        .
        case 2:



        case 7:
        return 1;

        default:
        cout<<"Crap entry Reenter \n\n\n\n\n";

    }


}while(a != 7);
return 0;
```

This is my code where i am trying to make a stack
And If i Enter a character in the switch case I get an infinite while loop Why is it so

Comment: What is the type of `a`? Because if it's e.g. `int` the input will only read an integer, and anything else will put the input stream `cin` in an error state.

Comment: A is an integer but I am getting infinite loop what do you mean by error state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note** the the declaration of `a` and the way it is initialized are FUNDAMENTAL to provide a proper answer, so please let that declaration visible in your snippet.

By the way, if `a` is an integer and in `cin` there is something that cannot be read as an int, `cin>>a` fails, cin is blocked (so any  further read will fail) and the value is **not read**.

As a consequence `a` will retain its old value (and chances are it will not be `7`, so no `return` is done) and it will never be changed.

The proper way to ensure a read can be to use, istead of `cin>>a`,

```
while(!(cin>>a))
{
    cout << "bad input: re-enter" << std::endl;
    cin.cler(); 
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
```

In other word, until `cin>>a` will not succeed, the error state is cleared, and whatever rubbish you may have int it, discarded, so that a new read will not re-read that same rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` then evaluates the character by its [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com), if the type of `a` is `char`.

If `a` is an `int`, inputting a character will set the `cin` stream to fail state (which can be queried with `cin.fail()`).

Comment: I am getting infinite loop please help me as to why it's so

Comment: @SagerGulabani Edited my answer. Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19696468/3425536) on how to handle incorrect input with `cin`.