# How to bail out of a while loop once a certain value is inputted into a variable

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that uses a while loop in C++. Here is my code so far:

```
    int userInput = 0;
    while (userInput != 'Z')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the homework score: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        homeworkScores.push_back(userInput);
        if (userInput == 'Z') {
            userInput = 'Z';
        }
    }
```

The problem im having is whenever I type Z, the loop keeps printing "Please enter the homework score: " over and over without stopping. I've defined homeworkScores as a vector earlier in the code. How can I make it stop the loop once userInput == 'Z'? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about making `userInput` `char` instead of `int`?

Comment: `cin >> userInput` reads an `int`, not a `char` as `'Z'` is.

Comment: if i make it a char will it still be pushed back in the vector homeworkScores (which is a int vector)?

Comment: You should catch up on how to convert a char to an int and the other way around.

Comment: What on earth is supposed to be the point of `if (userInput == 'Z') {
            userInput = 'Z';
        }`?

Comment: I was trying to set it to the char Z so it wouldn't run again because of the while(userInput != 'Z')

Comment: So, the normal operation is that the user enters integers which are pushed into homeworkScores, but when the user inputs a "Z" instead of an integer, the loop should exit, is that correct?

Comment: ```while(cin >> userInput)``` would exit once you output anything other than an integer. 'Z', 'A', 'qwerty' and others. Would that suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to exit a loop is by using the `break` statement.

```
if (userInput == 'Z') {
            userInput = 'Z';
            break;
        }
```

Other ways would be to set your exit condition to resolve as `false`, which I think is causing some issues for you.

EDIT: As @Ganea Dan Andrei noted, reading a char from `cin` into an integer will cause the `cin::fail()` to return `true`. This can be reset by calling `cin.clear()`, which will allow you to make further inputs.

`userInput` is an integer, and so 'Z' would have to equal the ASCII equivalent of its `char` value, which is `90`. The way you're doing it <strike>*should*</strike> *shouldn't* work. Instead, try making `userInput` a `char`, and then convert it to an integer so you can push it back into your vector. This might look like:

```
char userInput = '';
    while (userInput != 'Z')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the homework score: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        homeworkScores.push_back(userInput - '0'); //Are you sure you want to push a 'Z'?
        if (userInput == 'Z') {
            userInput = 'Z';
            break;
        }
        userInput = ''; // Reset your input so it doesn't keep getting pushed new values
    }
```

What happens here is `userInput - '0'` is subtracting the ASCII values of your chars, and leaving you with their integer value. There are other ways to do this, but this is a commonly used way.

Comment: Hey, while your solution works and (as you noted) is not a great idea, you should also notice that it has many (possible) bugs or unexpected behaviours at least: Input of "12" leads to 2 grade entries: 1 and 2, input of other characters is valid input: aBcZ results in 49 points, 28 points, 51 points and an end of the program.

Comment: His solution __shouldn't__ work, as reading  a char into an int with std::cin would result in std::cin.fail() returning true, not actually convering the char variable.

Comment: Thanks, just added a line to clear the input after each entry. Some of the logic I kept because we just can't know what his exact use cases are, but yeah, I agree the logic here seems wonky.

Comment: Even if you clear the input, this assumes all grades are between '0' and '9' which is often not the case.

Comment: @GaneaDanAndrei I thought so too at first, but they changed userInput to char (without me noticing at first), so it should work.

Comment: I'll add an explanation for the cin::fail(), thanks. As for the '0'-'9' inputs, I'm leaving it up to him to sanitize his inputs - that's not really within the scope of the question.

Comment: @Ketzu I meant the original ```This should work, but is considered bad form. ``` comment. Which was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing, is that `cin` is trying to read an integer, but you provide a character in the input. `cin` will only ask for another input, once the input is empty, you can try this by supplying more than one integer to your code:

```
Please enter the homework score: 2 27 12 8
```

will input all four numbers and print "Please enter the homework score: " 4 additional times.

If you provide it with a character, it will not remove it from the input, so whenever "cin" is reached, it will see "Z" in the input, and continue.

You can use answers like provided here [How to catch invalid input in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696442/how-to-catch-invalid-input-in-c) for your input sanitation, but it will not make "Z" work as a stop.

The easiest way is to chose an invalid score like -1 instead of Z, end on any invalid input or try to read a string on failure to read an int.